# Navigating between app icons in Unity with the keyboard

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, unity-2d

I just installed Ubuntu with Unity-2d inside VMWare. I press <kbd>Super</kbd> to search for an app, I start typing something like "te" and then get a bunch of apps. How do I navigate between them with the keyboard?

**EDIT:** Please don't post an answer before you verified that it works. I want to know which keys actually work, not which keys are *supposed* to work.

Comment: Pressing TAB enables you to select any of the listed apps. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Everyone: This is probably a bug in Unity-2d

Comment: is the bug filed, is there a bug number?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use the arrow keys to navigate.

For example, if I wanted to open Gedit, I could press <kbd>super</kbd> then type 'ge'.

[image]

Then I would press <kbd>↓</kbd>. This would highlight the 'See x more results' text.

[image]

Then I would press <kbd>↓</kbd> again. This would highlight the first application.

[image]

Then I would press <kbd>→</kbd> to select the second application (Gedit) and press enter to launch.

[image]

**Summary**

If an item in a row is highlighted, you can press the <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> items to move between them.
You can move between rows with the <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> buttons. Initially no row is selected so you need to press <kbd>↓</kbd> until an item in the first row is selected. You can use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to move between all possible selections.

Comment: You make great screenshots, but your solution simply doesn't work. Nothing happens when I push these buttons. This is probably a bug with Unity-2d.

Comment: While admittedly I am not using Unity-2D, the instructions work for me under Unity with Compiz.